# How to pass list of strings to a CFFI extension?

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

I would like to pass a list of strings to a CFFI extension which expects a `char**` as input parameter.

Example:

`extension.h`:

```c
#include <stddef.h>

void sort_strings(char** arr, size_t string_count);
```

`extension.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int cmpstrp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strlen(*(const char**)p1) < strlen(*(const char**)p2);
}

void sort_strings(char** arr, size_t string_count) {
    qsort(arr, string_count, sizeof(char*), cmpstrp);
}

// `main` is defined only for testing if `sort_strings` works as expected
int main(void) {
    char* string_list[] = {"cat", "penguin", "mouse"};
    size_t string_count = sizeof(string_list)/sizeof(string_list[0]);
    sort_strings(string_list, string_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < string_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", string_list[i]);
    }
}
```

`extension_build.py`:

```py
from cffi import FFI

ffibuilder = FFI()

ffibuilder.cdef('void sort_strings(char** arr, size_t string_count);')

ffibuilder.set_source('_extension',
    '#include "extension.h"',
    sources=['extension.c'],
    libraries=[])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

`demo.py`:

```py
from _extension.lib import sort_strings
from _extension import ffi


string_list = ["cat", "penguin", "mouse"]
bytes_list = [s.encode("latin1") for s in string_list]
cdata_list = ffi.new("char **", bytes_list)

sort_strings(cdata_list, len(string_list))

# print sorted list
```

How to test:

```bash
python extension_build.py
python demo.py
```

I have tried passing `string_list`, `bytes_list` and `cdata_list` as first input argument to `sort_strings`. I get these error messages:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not str
```

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not bytes
```

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a cdata pointer, not list
```

How can I pass my list of strings correctly (if possible without copying the list)?

(Just in case my intention is not clear: I'm not asking how to sort a list in Python.)

**SOLUTION:**

(Based on Armin Rigo's answer.)

It works when `demo.py` is updated like this:

```py
from _extension.lib import sort_strings
from _extension import ffi


string_list = ["cat", "penguin", "mouse"]
bytes_list = [ffi.new("char[]", s.encode("latin1")) for s in string_list]
pointer = ffi.new("char*[]", bytes_list)

sort_strings(pointer, len(string_list))

for s in pointer:
    print(ffi.string(s).decode("latin1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
cdata_list = ffi.new("char **", bytes_list)
```

with

```
cdata_list = ffi.new("char *[]", bytes_list)
```

because `ffi.new("T*")` allocates a single `T` and returns a pointer to it, whereas `ffi.new("T[]", length_or_list)` allocates an array of multiple `T`.

**EDIT:**

Ah no, another problem is that you have to allocate each `char *` explicitly, so you need:

```
bytes_list = [ffi.new("char[]", s.encode("latin1")) for s in string_list]
```

and then this `bytes_list` can be passed directly as argument to `sort_string()` (or you can pass `cdata_list` as above, but CFFI will do the same thing if you just pass `bytes_list` directly).

**EDIT 2:**

Passing `bytes_list` or `cdata_list` is not 100% equivalent: if you make an explicit `cdata_list` and use it in the call, then you can read from it after the call to learn how the C function changed this C array (as it does in your example).  If you pass `bytes_list` instead, then CFFI converts it to the same C array before the call, but frees the C array immediately after the call.

Comment: Thanks. This runs without error. But it does not work as expected: The list is not sorted after calling `sort_strings`. As if `sort_strings` was receiving a copy of the list instead of pointers. Any idea why?

Comment: I can verify this: Now I'm printing the list within `sort_strings`: Here it's sorted.

Comment: OK, it works like this: Create a pointer to `bytes_list`: `pointer = ffi.new("char*[]", bytes_list)`. Then pass this pointer to the function: `sort_strings(pointer, len(string_list))`.

Comment: Yes, if you pass a plain list, then it's not going to be modified by the call (it's converted to a C array internally before the call, and the C array is freed immediately after the call).  But if you pass a cdata of type `char *[]` then this, as a C array, will reflect changes done in C.